# FInd the time required by cars in a queue to reach destination if the car cannot exceed the speed of previous car? [Python Array sorting]

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, sorting

Suppose I have N number of cars in a series of array on road with speed of each car given in the array.

> speed = [5, 10, 7, 13, 15, 10, 16]

The array above is speed of each car. The distance between cars is 1 unit from each other.
i.e 5 is at postion 1, 10 is at position 2 and so on.

The condition:
The car must follow the speed of previous car to reach the position. I.e the cars cannot overtake each other.
Find the time required by each car.

My code:

```
list1 = [15, 20, 6, 3, 10]
count = 0

for x in range(1,len(list1)):
    if(list1[x] >= list1[x-1]):
        list1[x] = list1[x-1]
        count += list1[x-1]-list1[x] + 1
        list1[x] = list1[x-1]+1
print(list1)
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

```
list1 = [15, 20, 6, 3, 10]
count = 0

for x in range(1,len(list1)):
    if(list1[x] >= list1[x-1]):
        list1[x] = list1[x-1]
print(list1)

for i,j in enumerate(list1, start=1):
    time = i/j
    print(time)
```